# Obtener los empleados activos en un mes y año especifico

Tags: python, django

Un saludo para todos.

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde debo generar un **reporte de empleados activos**:

```
class Empleado(models.Model):
    identificacion = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('identificación'), max_length=10, unique=True)
    apellido = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('primer apellido'), max_length=80)
    nombre = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('primer nombre'), max_length=80)
```

Los empleados pueden ser contratados (`Ingreso`) en varias ocaciones:

```
class Ingreso(models.Model):
    empleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('empleado'), related_name='ingreso_empleado', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    fecha_ingreso = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('fecha de ingreso'))
    cargo = models.ForeignKey(Cargo, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('cargo'), related_name=('ingreso_cargo'), on_delete=models.PROTECT
    )
    compensacion_mensual = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('compensación mensual'))
```

Cada contrato puede ser finalizado (`Retiro`) con sus respectivas anotaciones:

```
class Retiro(models.Model):
    empleado = models.ForeignKey(Empleado, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('empleado'), related_name='retiro_empleado', on_delete=models.PROTECT )
    ingreso = models.OneToOneField(Ingreso, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('ingresó'), related_name='retiro_ingreso', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    fecha_terminacion = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('fecha de terminación'))
    observacion = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name=_('observación'), max_length=2, choices=MotivoRetiro.choices)
```

---

Estoy generando un reporte que recibe por un formulario el mes y ell año a reportar, y necesito saber cuales empleados estuvieron activos en ese periodo de tiempo.

Ejemplo:

```
EMPLEADOS:

nombre: Patricia
apellido: Sánchez
ingresó: 19-06-1984
retiro: 10-10-1998

nombre: Javier
apellido: Gómez
ingresó: 27-03-1993
retiro: 21-11-2002

nombre: Francisco
apellido: Diaz
ingresó: 06-02-2001
retiro: None  # (está activo)

nombre: Patricia
apellido: Sánchez
ingresó: 23-09-2001
retiro: 10-09-2007

nombre: Laura
apellido: Tello
ingresó: 13-08-2010
retiro: None  # (está activo)
```

No sé como filtrar los datos, pero la función inicia así:

```
def reporte_novedades(mes_reporte, anio_reporte)
    return Empleado.objecs.filter.......

reporte_novedades(10, 2001)
```

El resultado esperado seria el siguiente:

```
<QuerySet[<Empleado: Javier>, <Empleado: Francisco>, <Empleado: Patricia>]>
```

Es la misma `Patricia Sánchez` pero con 2 contratos diferentes. La que sale en el resultado es la del contrato que se encuentra vigente en el periodo solicitado.

Agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes incorporar a tu modelo empleados

```
activo = models.BooleanField(default = True)
```

Indicando que los empleados están activos o no
En tu comprobación solo verificas tu campo activo

Cada vez que ingreses un empleado se activara y solo necesitas desactivarlo cuando ya no laboren.

Coloque D`efault=True` ya que si tienes datos en tu BD y no colocas el default te traera un error, asi todos se pondran como activos y solo seleccionas los que ya no estan o colocar False y solo activar los que si estan laborando, solo es cuando incorpores el nuevo campo

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo tu función, seria así:

```
def reporte_novedades(mes_reporte, anio_reporte):
    empleados_activos = []

    for empleado in Empleado.objects.all().select_related():
        ingreso = empleado.ingreso_empleado.get(
            fecha_ingreso__year = anio_reporte, fecha_ingreso__month = mes_reporte,
        )

        try:
            empleado.retiro_empleado.get(ingreso = ingreso)
        except:
            empleados_activos.append(empleado)

    return empleados_activos
```

Filtrara los **empleados activos de ese mes y año** indicados.

Cabe recalcar que esto no es preciso, por ejemplo, los empleados que hayan estado activos unos días o semanas en el mes de octubre del 2020 pero en ese mismo mes y año se retiraron, no aparecerán en la siguiente filtración:

```
reporte_novedades(10, 2020)
```

Esto se debe a que los datos recibidos (mes y año) no son muy precisos, entonces si queremos evitar esto y ser mas precisos en las filtraciones, seria requerido filtrar también por días (lo cual es un poco mas complejo). (hay que considerar esto)

Espero haberte ayudado.